# How to filter a TFDTable by the Filter property on a boolean field?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am using FireDAC to connect to a SQL Server and I have a table with a boolean field "IsUser". Now I want to filter this table using the following code:

```
Tbl.Filter := 'IsUser = 1';
Tbl.Filtered := True;
```

After setting `Filtered` to `True`, the table component filters out all the records (I get an empty dataset), although there's a lot of records matching the filter.

If I do a select `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE IsUser = 1` all the records are shown.

When I use the filter `Tbl.Filter := 'IsUser <> 0'`, then I can see the same resultset as with the above `SELECT` query.

Does anybody know why the filter `IsUser <> 0` works whilst `IsUser = 1` does not? I want to switch a big project to FireDAC and have a lot of code using `Tbl.Filter := 'Field = 1'` so I would prefer getting this one to work.

Comment: Why aren't you using tbl.Filter := 'IsUser = true' ?

Comment: As I am using SQL Server the syntax "true" is not allowed. Boolean-Values must be specified with "1" for "true" and "0" for "false".

Comment: Firedac must handle table filters different than SQL text.. try using IsUser = True in the filter and report back.

Comment: Firedac does handle table filters differently to SQL text. At least with Delphi 10 Seattle, in the Filter property you have to have `= true` or `= false`, but in SQL `= 1` or `= 0`. Not sure why, but I'd also like to know if there's a way of unifying this, so one can use the same query for example to get the number of records in a filtered query with `FDQuery.Connection.ExecSQLScalar ('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tbl WHERE ' + FDQuery.Filter)`??